# pig join with java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: apache-pig

I have two files, in `data1`

```
1 3
1 2
5 1
```

In `data2`

```
2 3
2 4
```

I then tried to read them into pig

```
d1 = LOAD 'data1';
d2 = foreach d1 generate flatten(STRSPLIT($0, ' +')) as (f1:int,f2:int);
d3 = LOAD 'data2' ;
d4 = foreach d3 generate flatten(STRSPLIT($0, ' +')) as (f1:int,f2:int);
data = join d2 by f1, d4 by f2;
```

Then I got

```
2013-08-04 00:48:26,032 [Thread-21] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0005
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.HDataType.getWritableComparableTypes(HDataType.java:85)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Map.collect(PigGenericMapReduce.java:112)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.runPipeline(PigGenericMapBase.java:285)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:278)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
```

Could anybody help me? Thank you.

Comment: Do you need any more help with this question?

Answer (score 8):

First I'd define a simple schema for the inputs. Based on your example I assume that your inputs are text files.
Now you get the ClassCastException because just applying the schema *(f1:int, f2:int)* unfortunately won't do any conversion. You need to explicitly cast the output schema of `STRSPLIT` to `(tuple(int,int))` so that flatten can generate `f1:int and f2:int` from it. I.e:

```
d1 = LOAD 'data1' as (line:chararray);
d2 = foreach d1 generate flatten((tuple(int,int))(STRSPLIT($0, ' +'))) 
       as (f1:int,f2:int);

d3 = LOAD 'data2' as (line:chararray);
d4 = foreach d3 generate flatten((tuple(int,int))(STRSPLIT($0, ' +')))
       as (f1:int,f2:int);

data = join d2 by f1, d4 by f2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UDFs in your pig and get this casting exception, besides checking your pig script, also check your UDF script and make sure the actual returned value types match the `@outputSchema` types.