# Unable to dump a relation in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

Been stuck at a problem since very long. Any help would be appreciable.
So I have a dataset file in /home/hadoop/pig directory. I can view that file, thus no permissions issue.
The dataset has 4 columns separate by "::" as delimiter.
I'm running pig in local mode from inside /home/hadoop/pig directory.

```
ratingsData = LOAD 'ratings.dat' AS (line:chararray);

ratings = FOREACH ratingsData GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(.*?)::(.*?)::(.*?)::(.*?)')) AS (uid:int, mid:int, rating:int, timestamp:long);

grouped_mid = GROUP ratings BY mid;

dump grouped_mid;
```

The above script fails. I can successfully dump 'ratingsData' and 'ratings' relations but not the grouped_mid. But here's the bizarre part. The below script runs successfully.

```
ratingsData = LOAD 'ratings.dat' AS (line:chararray);

ratings = FOREACH ratingsData GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(.*?)::(.*?)::(.*?)::(.*?)')) AS (uid:int, mid:int, rating:int, timestamp:long);

STORE ratings INTO 'ratingInfo.txt';

X = LOAD 'ratingInfo.txt' AS (uid:int, mid:int, rating:int, timestamp:long);

grouped_mid = GROUP X BY mid;

dump grouped_mid;
```

Obviously, the second script has a redundant step. I'm simply storing a relation and reloading it again. I want to avoid this.
Any clarification/explanation would be highly appreciable.

Thanks much.

Comment: I tried this on a micro (4-row) sized sample of the same dataset.
I manually changed "::" to a comma in VI and loaded it into a relation using PigStorage,.ie., didn't use REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL.
It runs fine, and I'm able to dump grouped_mid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reference to this: [pig join with java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038760/pig-join-with-java-lang-classcastexception-java-lang-string-cannot-be-cast-to-j)

You can modify your scripts to:

```
ratingsData = LOAD 'ratings.dat' AS (line:chararray);

ratings = FOREACH ratingsData GENERATE FLATTEN((tuple(int, int, int, long))REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(.*?)::(.*?)::(.*?)::(.*?)')) AS (uid:int, mid:int, rating:int, timestamp:long);

grouped_mid = GROUP ratings BY mid;

dump grouped_mid;
```

Tested.